# insert array in mongo-db by factory in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I want insert array of link image insert to mongo-db by factory and faker

my factory:

```
$factory->define(App\Feed::class, function (Faker $faker)use ($fakerIR) {
return [
    'title'=>$fakerIR->text(15),
    'context'=>$fakerIR->text(),
    'images'=>[$faker->imageUrl(), $faker->imageUrl(), $faker->imageUrl()],
    'expires_at' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('now', '+1 months', 'Asia/Tehran'),
    'writer_id' =>$faker->randomElement(\App\User::where('role','=','administrator')->get()->pluck('id')),
];
});
```

and i caste images to array in Feed Model too

`protected $casts = [
       'images' => 'array ',
        'users_seen'=>'array'
    ];`

when i run db seed factory insert array list to mongodb as String not as array!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]in mongodb model don't need any casting field else data time , it work nice.
array casting use for auto converting  array to string for insert json to sql  .